# Version a "starter kit" to work upon in other projects

Tags: git, package, git-submodules, git-subtree, git-subrepo

All my projects have the same structure, base files (each containing some code).

Things I would like :

- Version this code ;
- Use it in other projects ;
- Be able to update it in those projects ;
- Only add code in those files, specific to each project (don't need to remove or to alter existing code).

I made some research. Using a package manager wouldn't suit my needs as i would like to add code to the package. I then found git submodules and subtrees and the latter seems to do the job.

What do you think about it ? Am I going in the right path by choosing subtrees or is there a better method ? Should I be using a complete different solution ?

Thanks guys

[EDIT]

More infos :

This "starter kit" is somewhat like a framework. I'm considering to build it in a way that doesn't need to edit its files in other projects but that would add constraints.

- I don't think submodules would fit as i need to work on the code ;
- Each project needs its own repo.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a master git repo, and clone that; you can have different branches for different variations of your base files.

This is pretty basic git usage.

Comment: Creating one branch per project in the "starter kit" repo is not a good idea. Each project needs its own repo for multiple reasons.

Comment: @AndréaMaugars not per project, per "skeleton variation".

Comment: And I didn't say you should put all projects in the same, repo @AndréaMaugars. I said you should clone a "template repo". That's different, fundamentally.

Answer (score 0):

This seems overly complicated, but depending on how similar the codebase is and whether they are actually different projects you might want to use branches or make one repo with the shared code and then just clone (or to be fancier, add as a submodule) that into the repos for other projects. So if your shared code is `shared` and you have projects `foo` and `bar` you'd make 3 separate repos and clone (or submodule add) `shared` into `foo` and `bar`. It really depends on how often you'll be updating `shared` and how separate `foo` and `bar` are

Comment: `foo` and `bar` might be completely different projects but they will be built upon the same structure and code. My understanding of submodule is quite limited. I think the fact i want to edit the submodule in each project will be problematic.